# Checkbox to button ngmodel - which way to change my value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I'd like to edit my checkbox so I get a  or an input with type=button instead.

I have for now, properly working :

```
<label>Afficher</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isElementVisible">
```

Simply, with my script-angular.js :

```
$scope.isElementVisible = false ; //it's working, true when I click on my checkbox.
```

I haven't been using AngularJS for a looong time cause that's an old project and I don't know how to say to the button that my ng-model needs to change, should I do a function or is there an easier way ?

Thanks in advance to you all :3

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not grasping what you're asking for. Please clarify what exactly your objective is.

Comment: I'd like to have something like : 
<input type="button" ng-model="isElementVisible"> and that in my angularJS isElementVisible is updated in my $scope like before when I had my checkbox... I don't know if that's clearer, let me know if not ;) thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can simply handle it in the html using

```
ng-click="isElementVisible = !isElementVisible"
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isElementVisible = false;
  }]);
```

```css
.hlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="isElementVisible = !isElementVisible">Click to toggle isElementVisible</button>
  <div ng-class="{'hlight':isElementVisible}">isElementVisible is {{isElementVisible}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! it seems so obvious right now, got something like that in my head but I had really forgotten the possible directives :) thanks again !

Comment: No prob. If this solved your question, feel free to mark it as the answer. THanks

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot again, I marked the answer as useful, is there another thing to do to mark it as THE answer ? :)

Comment: If you'd like to accept it as the solution, just click the checkmark to the left of the answer.